# Update pydantic from 1 to 2 field issues:

Tags: python, pydantic

I have the following code:

```
class _Sub(BaseModel):
    value1: str | None

class _Supra(BaseModel):
    supra_value1: str | None
    sub_value2: _Sub = Field(default_factory=_Sub)
```

In pydantic 1 doing `foo = _Supra(**{})` worked fine and created a model like `_Supra(_Sub(value1 = None) supra_value2=None)`

Now in pydantic 2 it returns:

```
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for _Sub
value1
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/missing
```

I tried several variants (Optional[_Sub], _Sub|None, Union[_Sub,None]) but none worked.

I just wanted to point out that before asking here I'm trying to understand the manual, ask google, ask chatgpt.

Comment: Read <https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/#required-optional-and-nullable-fields>, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the optional fields `value1` and `supra_value1` need to be provided default values. e.g.

```py
class _Sub(BaseModel):
    value1: str | None = None


class _Supra(BaseModel):
    supra_value1: str | None = None
    sub_value2: _Sub = Field(default_factory=_Sub)
```

Being optional they may hold a value of `None` but that value still needs to be set.

Comment: Thanks, big change from v1, where it was setted to None by default.